# Limit the number of revisions in Couchdb

Tags: couchdb

Is there a way to limit the number of revisions in couchdb? Something along the lines of a hard limit in a config file. I am aware of the fact that I could periodically compact the database, but somehow it feels like a hack. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no configurable limit, primarily because CouchDB uses append-only storage, i.e. it promises to only ever write to the end of a file and never change anything in the middle. As a result a configurable limit is meaningless.

Compaction is your only option. There has been some talk about automatically triggered compaction on the mailing lists but it can only be triggered manually for now.

Comment: Actually, there *is* a per-database revs per document limit. The default is 1000 but it can be changed by PUT'ing an integer to the database's _revs_limit resource, e.g. "curl http://localhost:5984/test/_revs_limit -X PUT -d 50".

You'll still need to compact to get the disk space back so it doesn't really change my previous answer as far as the question is concerned, you'll just get a bit more disk space back with a lower _revs_limit.

I don't know how much space it really saves, and a low _revs_limit may affect replication.

Comment: Note that this _revs_limit only affects how much revision *metadata* is stored after compaction; the document data from previous revisions is always discarded during compaction except for _revs_limit records of the *existence* of such-and-such a revision.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible on a per database basis through this HTTP API:

```
PUT /{db}/_revs_limit
```

Sets the maximum number of document revisions that will be tracked by CouchDB, even after compaction has occurred. You can set the revision limit on a database with a scalar integer of the limit that you want to set as the request body.

See https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/misc.html#db-revs-limit